# Is there any possible way to filter movelets using mel from another movlet?

Tags: movilizer

Is it possible to filter MOVELET based on string from another MOVELETS using MEL code? I had tried with `setMoveletFilter()` of MEL but it is not suitable for my requirement. Filter criteria is on another movelet. Based on that criteria I need to show Movelets on menu.

Do we have any way to do it as my requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *visibleExpression* element.
If the expression equals *false* the Movelet is invisible and if the expression equals *true* the Movelet is visible. This expression can also be a method like *strEquals*

Comment: Hi Jaya Sankar,
you can use *indexOf* which returns *-1* if the first input String does not contain the second input String. 
There are also *startsWith* and *endsWith* as methods.