# Do we have any methods in mel to check string contained in some another String or not

Tags: movilizer

Do we have any methods in mel to check string contained in some another String or not.
For Example:
I had String like "mel".
I had Another String like "melcode".
Do we have any idea how to check the String "mel"  is available in String "melcode".

Answer (score 4):

num indexOf(str inputString1, str inputString2)

if the return value is -1 then inputString1 does not contain inputString2

Comment: Yes, Thanks. But its  works with Case sensitive.Do we have any Alternatives to work with case insensitive letters also.

Comment: No, but you could try to open the documentation which might allow you to find: str toLowerCase(str inputString) which is available for 2.4 clients and higher

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Is there any possible way to filter movelets using mel from another movlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725885/is-there-any-possible-way-to-filter-movelets-using-mel-from-another-movlet/)

Hi Jaya Sankar, you can use indexOf which returns -1 if the first input String does not contain the second input String. There are also startsWith and endsWith as methods.